# Different ways of expressing the metric tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors, dual-spaces

On the [Lecture 16 Part 1 of the Advanced Calculus lecture by James Cook](https://youtu.be/HKiTCsNg4Jo?t=43m48s) the last line of the following definition of the metric tensor

$$\begin{align}
g(x,y) &= g\left( \sum_i x^i e_i, \sum_j y^j e_j\right)\\[2ex]
&= \sum_{i,j}x^i\;y^j\;g(e_i,e_j)\\[2ex]
&=\left( \sum_{ij} g_{ij}\;e^i \otimes e^j  \right)\;(x,y)
\end{align}$$

is explained quickly and almost in passing. What is the idea behind this last step?

Comment: @James S. Cook Very useful lectures, but I can't make out the audio for this step...

Comment: There is really not much about it. It's basically a rephrasing of the line before it. $g_{ij}$ is defined as $g(e_i,e_j)$ and the tensor $e^i\otimes e^j$ when evaluated at $(x,y)$ gives back $x^iy^j$ since $e^k$ just gives back the $k$-th coordinate.

Comment: A type $(2,0)$ tensor is something in $V^*$ tensored with something in $V^*$. Ok, actually a lie, it is certainly a sum of such things. But, anyway, the answer here gives you the algebra for the step. My hard to understand sentence is commenting on what we should expect given the metric is a type $(2,0)$ tensor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of the tensor product, each $e^i \otimes e^j$ is a bilinear function which acts on $(x,y)$ as $(e^i \otimes e^j)(x,y) = e^i(x) e^j(y)$. The term $e^i(x)$ is just the $i$-th coordinate of $x$ with respect to the basis $(e_i)$ - in other words, $e^i(x) = x^i$. Hence,

$$ (e^i \otimes e^j)(x,y) = e^i(x) e^j(y) = x^i y^j $$

and so

$$ \left( \sum g_{ij} e^i \otimes e^j \right)(x,y) = \sum g_{ij} (e^i \otimes e^j)(x,y) = \sum g_{ij} x^i y^j $$

and this is the same as middle expression, taking into account that $g_{ij} := g(e_i, e_j)$.